Would observation affect the results of a double-slit experiment if the observation isn't recorded?
Given that, when an electron passes through the double slit experiment without observing the slit it goes through, it produces an interference pattern, and that, when you do observe which slit it goes through, it doesn't, would having the same detector for what slit it goes through without recording still prevent the formation of an interference pattern?
On a related note, if it is recorded, but deleted soon after, would it also still prevent the interference pattern? Would it matter if the slit that the electron passed through was recorded and then deleted on another device?

The word "observed" as used in quantum mechanics is different from the colloquial usage, and is not centered on human perception. This is a common question so I'm sure a duplicate will be found that contains the answer to your question.

For a fun, related thought experiment, see Wigner's friend

Simply "not recording" the observation is insufficient. You need to erase the observation using a quantum eraser.

Duplicate of Double slit with erasure but I can't flag it because it doesn't have an upvoted or accepted answer. Also similar to Double-slit experiment with erasing all the collected data and If we forget which slit the photon goes through, does it interfere again? which have the same problem.
